# Codeigniter matches return false

Tags: php, codeigniter

i tried to save account to the db.
when validating the form with form_validation, it always returning false, even when i tried to insert the correct value. heres the code

```php
public function save(){
            $params = $this->input->post();

            if(!empty($params['id_account']) && !empty($params['password']) ){

                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confPass', 'Confirmation Password', 'matches[password]');

            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('confPass', 'Confirmation Password', 'required|matches[password]');
            }


            $this->form_validation->set_data($params);
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_role', 'Role', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                unset($params['confPass']);
                $params['account_status'] = array_key_exists('account_status', $params) ? $params['account_status'] : ACCOUNT_STATUS_PENDING;  
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $this->user_model->save($params);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('notif', '<div class="alert alert-success">Berhasil menyimpan data.</div>');
                redirect('rbac/form/account');
            } else {
                $error = validation_errors();

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($error);
                echo '</pre>';

                var_dump($params['password']);
                var_dump($params['confPass']);
                die();
                
                // $this->session->set_flashdata('notif', '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$error.'</div>');
                // redirect('rbac/form/account');
            }
        }
```

i tried to returning the `validation_errors()`, `$params['confPass']` & `$params['password']` and here is the result :

> The Confirmation Password field does not match the password field.
>
> string(1) "e" string(1) "e"

as you can see `$params['confPass']` and `$params['password']` is match.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($params['id_account']) && !empty($params['password']) ){
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('confPass', 'Confirmation Password', 'matches[password]');
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('confPass', 'Confirmation Password', 'required|matches[password]');
        }
```

When the condition you wrote above is true i.e. control is in if (below) block

```
if(!empty($params['id_account']) && !empty($params['password']) )
```

you did not put a condition for the 'password' field you only have confirm password rule. Which does not match to anything and although the passwords match it always return false.

You need to add validation rule for password

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
```

before confirm password rule which is looking to match the password.

If your condition states that it does not require password you can do something like,

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'min_length[5]');
```

anything which fulfills your condition but not "required" i.e trim or min_length

Hope it helps.